# How to test HOC component that provides context variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I've created a HOC for my [form component](https://codesandbox.io/s/xr5r1n2xzo), it exposes few functions as `context` variables. Here is the code:

```
// React 15


import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      shouldValidateForm: false
    };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      setFieldValue: (event, field) => {
        const fieldName = field.id;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
          [fieldName]: {
            ...prevState[fieldName],
            value: event.currentTarget.value
          }
        }));
      },

      addField: data => {
        this.setState({
          [data.id]: data
        });
      },
      formData: this.state
    };
  }

  /**
   * React Lifecycle Method: Renders the data
   *
   * @return {DOM} Main container DOM.
   */
  render() {
    return <form action="">{this.props.children}</form>;
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
    addField: PropTypes.func,
    setFieldValue: PropTypes.func,
    formData: PropTypes.object
  };
}
```

I want to unit test `addField`, `setFieldValue` in unit tests. I tried a few things but I couldn't figure it out. Can someone please point me in right direction about how to test it..

Comment: can you provide what you tried and by the way from where are you getting props ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy I tried to `mount` the component in enzyme and then used `.context` API to get the child(a dummy class component) component context, but turns out that you can get context of root element. My issue here is I want to access `addField` and `setFieldValue` functions in my test file and I am not sure how to achieve that.

Not sure what props are you talking about? did you get a chance to look into the link I provided in the top?